# Выделение числа (int)

Tags: php

Мне посоветовали отделять число от руб способом int, но сейчас появилась проблема. Если число записано как 1 200, то способ не работает. Как можно это исправить?

```
$this->edit5->text.=$array['response']['items'][$i]['thumb_photo']. ';';
$this->editAlt->text.=(int)$array['response']['items'][$i]['price']['text']. ';';
```

Comment: Удалите пробелы с помощью `str_replace()`, например

Comment: Ну или регулярка, которая цифры одни будет извлекать

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку при таком коде
$this->editAlt->text.=(int)$array['response']['items'][$i]['price']['text'].str_replace(' ', ''). ';';

Comment: Название ошибки str_replace() expects at least 3 parameters

Comment: @Ракан почему ты `str_‌​replace` применяешь так, как ты написал? Может в документации посмотришь как правильно надо?

Comment: Мой никнейм прямо обо мне говорит, я ракан в программировании, иначе бы не писал сюда, сорич.

Comment: Но ведь ты читать умеешь, правда? А документацию надо посмотреть, почитать и понять. Для этого SO не нужен О_о

Answer (score 1):

Заменяйте все не числовые данные.
Пример регулярного выражения

```
preg_replace('#[^\d]*#', '', $value)
```

В вашем случаи можно записать так

```
// Для удобства, назначаем переменной
$price = $array['response']['items'][$i]['price']['text'];
// Заменяем, всё кроме цифр 
$price = preg_replace('#[^\d]*#', '', $price);
// Передача дальше
$this->editAlt->text .= $price . ';';
```

*Есть один момент, если данные у вас будут не строковые, а скажем `float` то при `1.05` у вас получится `105` помните об этом*

Comment: Хотел поставить лукас, но пока что не могу, репы не хватает, но скажу спасибо хотя бы на буковках :)

Comment: руб не удаляется.

Comment: @Ракан `var_dump($price)`, до замены что выдаёт? Возможно руб где-то в другом месте подставляется

Answer (score 0):

Немного грубо но.

```
echo (int)str_replace(' ', '', '1 200 руб');
#исключит пробелы и сделает приведение к int, мне кажется это очень не правильно.
#Вывод "1200"
```

Или, регулярка

```
echo preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', '1 200 руб'); 
#исключит из строки все что не является цифрами
#Вывод "1200"
```

Или, для вывода

```
echo rtrim(preg_replace('/[^0-9^ ]/', '', '1 200 руб'));
# Выйдет String, но "1 200" preg_replace исключил все символы кроме цифр и пробела
# А rtrim исключил все пробелы в конце строки.
```